# python: compare if the first and second elements in 2 different list then same?

Tags: python, list, compare

How can I compare first and second elements in 2 different list and if fist and second element match both list it will display pattern repeat and if not equal its will display not match.

if any(map(lambda v: v in patterns2, patterns)): will compare all

```
patterns = userinput
patterns2 = userinput2


if any(map(lambda v: v in patterns2, patterns)):
    print ('Pattern appears 2 time!')
else:
    print("Number not in list")
```

Comment: Do you want to check order as well?  That would be `patterns[:2]==patterns2[:2]`.

Comment: Thank for the reply ….I will compare list 1,2,3,4,5 to 1,2 ..1,2 is in both list its will display pattern appears 2 time else number not in list